# Are there an infinite number of powers of 2 with no 0's in their base 3 representation?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Obviously, leading zeroes are ignored.  I have no idea whether this is an easy or hard question, or how one would go about solving something like this.

This question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33942/do-the-base-3-digits-of-2n-avoid-the-digit-2-infinitely-often-what-is-the discusses a likely related question,  but the two links provided in the answer are both to pieces of media that no longer exist.

Comment: I am not having any trouble acccessing Lagarias's slides.

Comment: "You have requested a resource that is not available on the U-M Personal web server. It is difficult to guess why this is the case on a server with so many different, unrelated web pages, but the page, image, or resource you requested is not available at this time."

Comment: Looks hard to me.

Comment: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~lagarias/TALK-SLIDES/talks.html try the link here maybe?

Comment: Just found this http://neilsloane.com/doc/persistence.2.jpg from 1973, suggests that the problem is indeed hard.